# Error al iniciar MySQL con XAMPP en Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp

hace unas semanas instalé en Ubuntu Xampp y me ha estado funcionando perfectamente para crear una BD en phpmyadmin.
Hoy he ido a iniciar Xampp y me han saltado los siguientes errores:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.4.29...
XAMP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.

~$ /otp/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 263: kill: NO such process

~$ sudo service mysql start Failed 
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

No se por qué no me encuentra el servicio de MySQL..

Podría ser porque...A la hora de guardar un archivo PHP en htdocs me daba un error de permiso, por lo que cambie el propietario de lampp a mi usuario en vez de dejarlo en Root.
Ya me deja guardar el archivo PHP pero ahora no se me inicia mysql correctamente y debe ser por el cambio, que fue incorrecto. Como puedo volver a hacer a root propietario de lampp? Al intentar utilizar el comando  `chmod root -R lampp` Me da error. Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No tiene pinta de ser eso, sino más bien que no encuentra el servicio mysql.  Vete a un terminal y escribelo a pelo, a ver que te dice (seguramente lo mismo), así; `sudo service mysql start`  y luego mira los errores con `sudo service mysql status` a ver si sacas mas info al respecto.  tambien prueba de ejecutar `mysql` a secas en un terminal a ver si lo encuentra o por algun oscuro motivo a desaparecido de tu ubuntu, y si acaso buscalo con `which mysql` para que te indique su ruta si aun existe

Comment: @masterguru esta pregunta esta mucho mejor para mi opinión en [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) en esa pagina es mas de técnicos que de programación

Comment: Me lo apunto, muchas gracias!

Comment: por lo que veo @NdeNoob te la han eliminado la [pregunta...](https://serverfault.com/questions/1100122/mysql-is-not-found-in-xampp-ubuntu)

Comment: prueba en este [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @masterguru creo que deberíamos echarle un cable aunque este sitio no sea el adecuado... le han cerrado la pregunta de serverfault

Comment: @JavierG.Raya No se, yo ya le he dado instrucciones en mi primer comentario y dDe momento no ha dicho nada, ya dira algo si quiere, y si podemos (y tenemos tiempo, que a mi empieza a escasearme hoy) le ayudamos en comentarios

Comment: vale @masterguru :-)

Comment: actualmente tengo el mismo problema y de las diferentes respuestas que el leido puedo concluir lo siguiente.
1. si instalo el Xampp para de ahi tomar los servicios de apache y MYSQL y no se instalo mysql por aparte como suelen hacer algunas personas, acceder al mysql desde el home usando los comandos sudo service mysql start no van a funcionar ni ningún otro comando de esos te va a arrojar nada, en mi caso personal la salida en consola es: Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
usando cualquier comando que invoque al mysql
en ese sentido la única forma de acceder al mys

Comment: chmod es permisos chown es propietario